# AMchart data in MMM-yyyy format

Tags: javascript, amcharts

Is it possible to render amchart with date in MMM-yyyy format as my data is in MMM-yyyy format

I tried to set

```
"dataDateFormat": "MMM-YYYY"
```

along with

```
"categoryAxis": {
      "parseDates": true,
      "minPeriod":"MM",                   
 },
```

but amchart shows wrong data

Comment: Why the C# tag???

Comment: i am using in in .net application and chart data is fetched from aspx code behind

Comment: The C# tag isn't really relevant to your question because the question isn't about a problem with C# code. You could have the data generated in javascript and still have the same question. Note I'm not trying to complain, just explaining why it isn't necessary to tag C#. Have you had a look at the ["formatting dates"](https://www.amcharts.com/kbase/formatting-dates/) knowledge base for amcharts?

Comment: yes i looked it and set "dataDateFormat": "MMM-YYYY"

Comment: however, i don't know i am using it correctly or not

Comment: @KJV111 The knowledge base clearly states that MMM (along with M and MMMM) are not supported. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

[`dataDateFormat` doesn't support parsing MMM dates](http://www.amcharts.com/kbase/formatting-dates/). Note the asterisk by that format in the table and footnote:

> - the formatting codes marked with an asterisk are not supported in dataDateFormat setting. The chart will not be able to parse those from your string-based dates in data.

You need to provide a supported format upfront (for example MM-YYYY dates) either by modifying your payload or use external JS to reformat/parse those out first before passing it to AmCharts. [MomentJS](http://momentjs.com/) can parse those date formats into native date objects that can be used by AmCharts if you want to go that route.

Note that AmCharts can format the axis labels to MMM-YYYY for display purposes afterward by modifying the category axis' [`dateFormats` array](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/CategoryAxis#dateFormats)

```
"categoryAxis": {
  "parseDates": true,
  "minPeriod": "MM",
  "dateFormats": [ //you must provide the entire array
    {"period":"fff","format":"JJ:NN:SS"},
    {"period":"ss","format":"JJ:NN:SS"},
    {"period":"mm","format":"JJ:NN"},
    {"period":"hh","format":"JJ:NN"},
    {"period":"DD","format":"MMM DD"},
    {"period":"WW","format":"MMM DD"},
    {"period":"MM","format":"MMM-YYYY"}, //modify at least the month period to the desired format
    {"period":"YYYY","format":"YYYY"}
  ]
}
```